# MacVim doesn't start my rails server vim-ruby-debugger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, macvim, vim-plugin

I tried adding a good debugger for my rails project and I found vim-ruby-debugger to be the best option for my favourite editor VIM. This works perfectly with ubuntu.

But when I tried configuring it for my Mac the debugger prompts a started message but the rails server is down.

This is what I did.

- Installed gem ruby-debug-ide
- Installed plugin vim-ruby-debugger using pathogen
- Modified my .vimrc as

let g:ruby_debugger_progname = 'mvim' 
let g:ruby_debugger_debug_mode = 1 
let g:ruby_debugger_builtin_sender = 0

When I tried staring the rails as 
**:Rdebugger** 

it says Debugger started but it doesn't start my server.

Is there anything I need to configure additionally ?

Comment: Did you install MacVim by .dmg or via homebrew? Is mvim in your $PATH and working?

Comment: Hi Conner, I installed macvim from dmg and also from homebrew. Then I removed the conflicting homebrew version. Will it be a problem ?

Comment: Not necessarily, but is mvim in your $PATH and working? For example, if you type mvim on the command-line does it open MacVim?

Comment: Yes I am able to load the mvim by typing: mvim -v in my iterm2

Comment: What's the output of `:echo has("ruby")`?